# Android Internal Memory Issue

Tags: android

I have a game published on Android Market. Some users reported that it cannot be purchased and downloaded.The price won't show up to buy. My game is about 70mb, is it because of sized is too big for the internal memory of those phone so Google Market disabled the purchase?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the current App package size limit is 50 MB, but you can however reduce the app package itself to that size and add the aditional data content as two separate archives of 2 GB each, or at least this is what was mentioned at I/O 2011, as seen here: http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/05/11/io-2011-google-increases-app-size-limit-to-4gb-tweaks-the-return-policy/

In any case, as mentioned in that same link, regardless if those limits are the ones currently in use by the market or not, you can make your app post-download some data it needs, through internet, after installation. That solution will most likely always work as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. But I have verified it's not the memory space issue ruined my app downloads. Some people said they have tons of free internal memory and they can't even saw the "Buy" button in android market. While some others can get this app successfully from the market. That's weird. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the installLocation to external (see http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) and see if that helps with phones that don't have sufficient internal memory.